# Задача на умение работать с основными операциями в Java

Tags: java, алгоритм

**Здача звучит следующим образом:**

> В Григорианском календаре год является високосным в двух случаях: либо
>   он кратен 4, но при этом не кратен 100, либо кратен 400.
>
> Реализуйте метод, вычисляющий количество високосных лет с начала нашей
>   эры (первого года) до заданного года включительно. На самом деле
>   Григорианский календарь был введен значительно позже, но здесь для
>   упрощения мы распространяем его действие на всю нашу эру.

**Формат метода:**

```
public static int leapYearCount(int year) {
    return year;
}
```

Никак в голову ничего не приходит... В принципе, задача была бы простой. Но мне надо ее **решить без использования `if` и `for`**. Допустимы только арифметические и битовые операции. Может кто-то подскажет как решать или направит на путь истинный ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ну самый простой вариант - просто посчитать. Високосный год каждый 4 - т.е. `year/4`. Но каждый 100 не високосный значит вычитаем `year/100`. Каждый 400 тем не менее високосный. Итого:

```
return year/4 - year/100 + year/400;
```

Я предполагаю что 0 года не было.

А вообще (не в учебных целях) я бы использовал методы нужного класса от интерфейса `Calendar`.